# Maximum smarty Math value

Tags: html, math, smarty

This is my code:

```
<td class="bezcat bg{math equation="floor(x/8)+1" x=$dag.wp.0}">{$dag.wp.1}<br/><i>({$dag.wp.0})</i></td>
```

What my code does, is calculate a value depending on a number (x) and make a classname of it (bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4 or bg 5). Each classname has it's own background color, a low x (`x<=8`) will have a green background color, a big x (`x>=40`) will be red.

My calculation works great, except for one point. I have only named 5 classnames in my css (bg1 to bg5), so when the calculated value will be greater then 5 (let's say with `x=100`) my classname will be bg12 and is not described in my css. What's the best way to perform that when my calculated value is bigger than 5 my classname will still be bg5. Something with if-statements maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beforehand: this is untested.

Smarty supports the PHP [min](http://php.net/manual/de/function.min.php) function. So you could use this:

```
{math equation="min(5, floor(x/8)+1)" x=$dag.wp.0}
```

As a note from the Smarty documentation [{math}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.math.tpl):

> {math} is an expensive function in performance due to its use of the php eval() function. Doing the math in PHP is much more efficient, so whenever possible do the math calculations in the script and assign() the results to the template.